# Is the VoIP kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP CFStream option flag effective for TCP server sockets on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, background, cfstream

I am making an iOS application where I have a TCP server socket (listening on some port) which is used to handle incoming connections and I would like to know if the kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP options will be effective with it.

The use case is that I need the application to be able to handle new connections while it is in the background. Can this be achieved?

Thank you for your insights.
woodleg.as

Comment: After many experiments, some successful others not. I am concluding that in order for the OS to honor the voip flag in a server socket that server socket MUST have accepted at least one connected socket and the accepted socket NEEDS to be still active. 

In other words, the flag is ineffective on server sockets.